# Unable to find my app on the app store

Tags: iphone, app-store, app-store-connect

Finally, thanks to most of you, I got my first app approved by Apple. The problem is that I'm only able to find it on the app store if I click on the link provided on iTunesConnect.

If I try to search with any of the keywords I inserted in the metadata I don't find my app.

One more thing the link is like this:

http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/gearup/id441500177?mt=8&ls=1

does the `"/us/"` mean that it is only on the american app store. I didn't select any specific country (they are all selected).

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can remove the /US/ from the link. You're just seeing that error because the US store is not your default.

The link works for me and shows your app on itunes.com before launching the iTunes application

Your searches may not work until your app has been propagated to all the various stores. Sometimes that can take a while.

Answer (score 2):

Immediately after going live and having been accepted, there will always be a small amount of time while the app propagates across the Apple servers.

Your link works as koregan stated, and yes the /us/ is the country code. For example, if you replace it with fr then you see the web page in French - if you localized the app then you will see the app information with the text you would have supplied; else you will see it in English.